# Question related Checkboxes in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, listview, checkbox

My question is;I have a listview which can be filled through a code.I put one checkbox in template section for every item. how many data comes automatically,the checkbox creating that.I wanna do thing;I want to choose only 20-pieces from that checkboxes and I want to do a process on it.Finally,I'm using asp.net.

Regards,

Comment: Sorry, that is way too vague. You're not explaining the problem adequately.

Comment: English grammar...sorry...are you talking about textbox properties, or are you saying you want to find checkboxes in the first 20 records of your listview...please clarify

Comment: @kuru kuru na-I'm sorry,yes,as you said,I want to find checkboxes in the first 20 records of my listview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this then...

```
dim myCounter as integer = 1
dim myCheckBox as checkbox

for each myItem as listviewitem in me.listview.items
   myCheckbox= CTYPE(myItem.FindControl("mycheckbox_name"),checkbox)
   'do your processing on it
   If myCounter >= 20 then exit for
   myCounter += 1
next
```